# Python isinstance of class within same class' definition

Tags: python, python-typing, typing

I want to do something like

```
class my_class:
    def __add__(self, other: "my_class") -> "my_class":
        if isinstance(other, some_other_class):
            return other + self
        elif isinstance(other, my_class):
            return <special_adding_technique>
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError()
```

But I can't, as I can't reference my_class inside of itself. I can do some duck typing, with try except, or check `has_attr`, but this is far less clean than simply checking `isinstance`. What can I do which is simple and doesn't look hacky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference `my_class` inside itself just fine. You can't refer to `my_class` while it's being defined (outside any method, at the top-level of the class definition scope, or in the parameter definitions of a function), but you can refer to it inside a method that won't be called until you've finished defining `my_class`. The only issue you have here is the somewhat ugly string-based annotations to work around the self-reference limitation, which can be fixed with a `__future__` import.

```
from __future__ import annotations  # Supported as of 3.7, on by default beginning in 3.11

class my_class:
    def __add__(self, other: my_class) -> my_class:
        if isinstance(other, some_other_class):
            return other + self
        elif isinstance(other, my_class):
            return <special_adding_technique>
        return NotImplemented   # When you can't work with the other type, you're supposed
                                # to return the NotImplemented singleton, not raise
                                # NotImplementedError, where the latter is for completely
                                # unimplemented functionality, usually in an ABC
```

As a side-note, Python classes are the exception to the normal naming rule of `lowercase` or `lowercase_with_underscores`; classes use `CapWords`, so this class should be named `MyClass` to comply with PEP8.

Comment: you're right.. my stupid linter refused to acknowledge that this is possible, initially giving me a red underline. it believes in me now, thanks

Comment: @JerryHalisberry: Cool. A bonus side-note: Your `if isinstance(other, some_other_class):
            return other + self` is likely wrong too. If `other` defines `__radd__` correctly (and it should), then that case can and should be handled by returning `NotImplemented` from `my_class.__add__`, just like you do for all other classes you don't know how to add yourself to. When you return `NotImplemented`, Python asks the right hand side if it knows how to perform the reflected operation (in this case, `__radd__`), and only if both sides return `NotImplemented` does it fail with a `TypeError`.